# UITableView display

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I add UIView in UITableviewcell. The first occurrence of all appears normal. But every time when you scroll all the strays. UILabel overlap with different values. Below is the code to create Cell. What am I doing wrong?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

float low_bound = 0;
float high_bound = 7;
float rndValue = (((float)arc4random()/0x100000000)*(high_bound-low_bound)+low_bound);

int dayStart = rndValue;
int dayMonth = 30;

int maxI = (dayStart+(7-dayStart))*(indexPath.row+1);

int Pos;

if (indexPath.row == 0) {
    dayNumber = dayStart;
    Pos = 0;

} else {

    Pos = dayNumber;
}

for (int i=dayNumber; i < maxI; i++) {

    UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(4, 4, 40, 40)];

    if (i > 0) {            
        CGRect frame = myView.frame;
        frame.origin.x = (44.0*(i- Pos-1));
        myView.frame = frame;
    }      

    UILabel *yourLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(24, 0, 40, 40)];

    [yourLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", i-dayStart+1]];

    [myView addSubview:yourLabel];

    [cell addSubview:myView];

    dayNumber++;
}

return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

THe cells you are using are being reused by the system, and every tieme that happens, you just slap another label on top of all the others. You need to either remove the labels before reusing the cell by doing something like

```
//this needs to be placd before the for-loop
for (UIView *view in cell.contentView.subViews){
    [view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

or you can keep references to the labels and just assign new values to them.
I would advise you to do the latter, but it will probably mean that you have to subclass UITableViewCell.

Right now, the code in your forloop keeps creating new labels and just stacks them up like a lasagna.

Comment: I have changed static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath]; no CalendarTableViewCell *cell = [[CalendarTableViewCell alloc]init]; If I scroll down all good except that the last column is not drawn. But if I scroll up a portion of the empty rows or just do them only a few uiview.

Comment: @Alexey - You are experiencing this issue because you are ignoring the fact that cells get reused. dequeReusableCellWithIdentifier will either get a reusableCell for you or a new cell will be alloc'ed and initialized for you, whether you like it or not. I strongly recommend that your read the fabulous manual.